# How to join between two collections when foreign key in an array of ObjectIs's

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the following collection structure for mongodb:

- users

  - id
  - userId
  - emailAddress
- products

  - id
  - sku
  - price
- productRewards

  - products: [{productId}],
  - pointsNeeded
  - rewardAmount
- productUsers

  - productId
  - userId

The mongoose schema is listed below:

```
UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    userName: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 6, maxlength: 10, required: true},
    emailAddress: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 8, maxlength: 55, required: true}
}

ProductSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    sku: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 30, required: true},
    price: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true}
}

ProductRewardSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    products: [{productId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'product'}}],
    pointsNeeded: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true},
    rewardAmount: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true}
}

ProductUserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    productId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product'},
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}
}
```

DB Version: 3.6

and I need to calculate the points users have accumulated to determine the rewards they are eligibility for.  How should I perform this in mongodb?  I know how this could be done in sql just not nosql.

I am trying something like this but am not sure this is right:

```
db.productUsers.aggregate(
    { "$unwind": "productRewards.products" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "productRewards",
            localField: "productRewards.products.productId",
            foreignField: "productId",
            as: "rewards"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            userId: "$userId", productId: "$productId", total:  { $sum: "$price" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            userId: 1,
            productId: 1,
            total: 1
        }
    }
)
```

Additionally I am expecting a json output like this:

{ "userId": "ObjectId string", "name": "product name string", "total": 50 }

Comment: Which mongo version ? What is your expected json response ? Can you also add some sample documents from your collection ?

Comment: @Veeram I updated my question.  I do not have any documents as of yet.  I am stuck on the initial starting point to formulating this query.

Comment: I mean the documents from your collection for example productUsers & productRewards. How is productRewards is related to productUsers ?

Comment: Gotcha.  productRewards and productUsers are not directly related.  They both have the _id field from the products collection as their foreign key, local key would be the productId field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start from productUsers collection and join to productRewards collection on productId and work from there.

Something like

```
db.productUsers.aggregate(
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "productRewards",
            localField: "productId",
            foreignField: "products.productId",
            as: "rewards"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            userId: 1,
            productId: 1,
            points: {$arrayElemAt:["$rewards.pointsNeeded", 0]}
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: How does the lookup work if productRewards.products is an array of productId?

Comment: It does  $in comparison. So it checks local field productId is in foreign field array of products.